# How to Access Array response of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my AJAX call response which is in array format

[1,2,3,4,5,6]

```
success: function(outputfromserver) {


$.each(outputfromserver, function(index, el) 
{ 


});
```

How can we access outputfromserver all values ??

Means outputfromserver Zeroth value is 1 , 2nd element is 2 , -----so on

Comment: What is your entire ajax call? What language is your server-side script?

Comment: `console.dir(outputfromserver)` should tell you what `outputfromserver` is and then you'll know how to access it. Maybe you have to [fresh up your JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) beforehand.

Comment: I am doing that console the log , but dont know how to process

Comment: It would be helpful to see your JavaScript AJAX call. Are you using $.getJSON(), or at least $.ajax() and specifying dataType as json?

Comment: You should post your whole jQuery ajax code (did you use `$.get()` or `$.post()` with "json" as the last argument or `$.getJSON()`?), not just the success callback, because that won't help us help you with much.

Comment: Server side code may be helpful too in this case.. so post it if possible/applicaple. btw. who said that returned data is json encoded...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would help to know what your AJAX request looks like. I recommend using $.ajax() and specifying the dataType as JSON, or using $.getJSON().

Here is an example that demonstrates $.ajax() and shows you how to access the returned values in an array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.json', // returns "[1,2,3,4,5,6]"
    dataType: 'json', // jQuery will parse the response as JSON
    success: function (outputfromserver) {
        // outputfromserver is an array in this case
        // just access it like one

        alert(outputfromserver[0]); // alert the 0th value

        // let's iterate through the returned values
        // for loops are good for that, $.each() is fine too
        // but unnecessary here
        for (var i = 0; i < outputfromserver.length; i++) {
            // outputfromserver[i] can be used to get each value
        }
    }
});
```

Now, if you insist on using $.each, the following will work for the success option.

```
success: function (outputfromserver) {

    $.each(outputfromserver, function(index, el) {
        // index is your 0-based array index
        // el is your value

        // for example
        alert("element at " + index + ": " + el); // will alert each value
    });
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I previously set my array as  dataType : 'text' and js didn't  recognize it

Answer (score 2):

The array is a valid JSON string, you need to parse it using JSON parser.

```
success: function(outputfromserver) {
    var data = JSON.parse(outputfromserver);
    $.each(data, function(index, el) { 
        // Do your stuff
    });
},
...
```

Comment: Not really. If jQuery knows that the response is JSON (and chances are that it does know) then the JSON is automagically parsed for you. Also, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: can i use data[0] there  to get the first element ?

Comment: Worked for me - simple solution for jquery get :-)

Answer (score 1):

### You can use JS objects like arrays

For example this way:

```
// Loop through all values in outputfromserver
for (var index in outputfromserver) {
  // Show value in alert dialog:
  alert( outputfromserver[index] );
}
```

This way you can get values at first dimension of array,
above `for..loop` will get values like this:

```
// Sample values in array, case: Indexed array
outputfromserver[0];
outputfromserver[1];
outputfromserver[2];
// So on until end of world... or end of array.. whichever comes first.
outputfromserver[...];
```

However, when implemented this way, by using `for ( index in array )` we not only grab indexed `1,2,3,4,...` keys but also values associated with named index:

```
// Sample values in array, case: accosiated/mixed array
outputfromserver["name"];
outputfromserver["phone"];
outputfromserver[37];
outputfromserver[37];
outputfromserver["myindex"];
// So on until end of world... or end of array.. whichever comes first.
outputfromserver[...];
```

In short, array can contain indexed values and/or name associated values, that does not matter, every value in array is still processed.

#### If you are using multidimensional stuff

then you can add nested `for (...)` loops or make recursive function to loop through all and every value.

Multidimensional will be something like this:

```
// Sample values in array, case: indexed multidimensional array
outputfromserver[0][0];
outputfromserver[0][1];
outputfromserver[1][0];
outputfromserver[1][...];
outputfromserver[...][...];
```

### Update, JSON object:

If you server returns JSON encoded string you can convert it to javascript object this way:

```
try { 
    // Try to convert JSON string with jQuery:
    serveroutputobject = $.parseJSON(outputfromserver); 
} catch (e) {
    // Conversion failed, result is not JSON encoded string 
    serveroutputobject = null;
}

// Check if object converted successfully:
if ( serveroutputobject !== null ) {
    // Loop through all values in outputfromserver
    for (var index in serveroutputobject) {
        // Append value inside <div id="results">:
        $('#results').append( serveroutputobject[index] + "<br/>" );
    }
}
// In my own projects I also use this part if server can return normal text too:
// This way if server returned array we parse it and if server returns text we display it. 
else {
    $('#results').html( outputfromserver );
}
```

More information [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)

Comment: Thanks so to access all elements , do i need to use for (var i in outputfromserver) {
         alert( i );
         console.log( value );
       }

Comment: @yyyi777 Now with bigger screen corrected some typos and added more detail, please read again as example is rewritten too.

Comment: @yyyi777 Here's small example I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Kw6A6/ You can do tests with it to make sure if it suits for your needs. Will's answer shows great quality too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url : url,
    data:dataString,
    success: function(return_data,textStatus) {



         temperature.innerText=return_data.temp;
                   // OR
        **temperature.innerText=return_data['temp'];**  

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert("Error while accessing api [ "+url+"<br>"+textStatus+","+errorThrown+" ]"); return false;    
    }
 });
```